# Windows Server 2008 R2 - NAT for VPN clients using single NIC

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server with a single NIC which is set up as a VPN server. I want my VPN users to be able to route all their internet traffic through this server once they have connected. I tried adding a local loopback adapter to compensate for the other NIC (adding the VPN's IP to the loopback interface) but that trick didn't work since I'm more of a developer than a sysadmin.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Somebody else might be able to chime in here but doesn't Routing and Remote Access VPN default to a bridged VPN configuration?  i.e. a virtual interface is assigned on the VPN server and this is also the gateway of the VPN clients, and all traffic is bridged onto the LAN this way?

Comment: The routing seems to work within the local network. For example, once I'm connected to the VPN, I can ping other interfaces of the server that are using different subnets than the one used by the VPN. I don't know if it's worth noting that the single NIC is configured with four other static/public IP address. It's confusing.

Comment: Umm, yeah, that sounds... odd.

Comment: Odd, nothing.  That sounds downright cruel.  I wouldn't know where to begin, except by adding another NIC, or a proper piece of network gear... or pouring myself a stiff drink.

Comment: Or perhaps a virtual/emulated network interface could do the trick? (other than MS local loopback adapter).